# How to create Docker file to install community edition of Rstudio IDE

Tags: docker, rstudio

I know about creating docker for Rstudio Server using below command

```
> RUN wget
> https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-1.1.456-amd64.deb \
>                            && gdebi -n rstudio-server-1.1.456-amd64.deb \
>                            && rm /rstudio-server-1.1.456-amd64.deb
```

But its throwing some errors while installing

I also wanted to install community edition for R-Studio IDE using Docker , and wanted to know how to create docker for the same.

I also referred the link below

> https://github.com/rocker-org/rstudio-daily

Comment: IDE inside Docker?) Maybe you look for VirtualBox or VMWare instead.. Docker is not suited for using GUI.

Comment: @grapes : okay So in that case can Rserver will serve my purpose? as it will open Rstudio server gui in new window?

Comment: If you want to run RStudio inside Docker - it's possible. Take a look here: https://hub.docker.com/r/indigodatacloudapps/kepler/ to take a look how to setup VNC server that you can access later. I know this doesn't address your issue directly, but may help you with further steps. It's quite useful to have Docker based env. especially in case you want to have full env. for tutorial purposes, etc.